# bash script getting the value from a variable of the form var$[id]

Tags: bash, shell

This is the first time Im using a shell script ( #!/bin/sh )  and Ive been working my way through it reading tutorials and the like but Im stuck on this reading and writing values of a key..

Im trying to read in key=value pairs from a config file of the form

```
key1_begin=abc
key1_end=def

key2_begin=123
key2_end=jkl

.. and so on
```

I would like the user to pass in parameters to the script like

```
something.sh 1 x y z
```

where the first parameter would serve as an  that is used to modify the appropriate keys. So after I have checked that the directory exists and the file exists I source it using

```
source config.cfg
```

I then save the id using ID=$1 and access the keys using

```
echo key${ID}_begin
```

so a read to obtain the value of the key would be

```
echo key${ID}_begin = $[key${ID}_begin]
```

where I expect to get  " key1_begin = abc " but instead keep getting " key1_begin = 0 ". The same command however seems to work work for numbers. For example using this command with an ID of 2 gives " key2_begin = 123 "

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to why this works fine for numbers but not alphabets?

And what do I use to change the value of the variable? I am currently using "eval" but this again seems to only work with numbers

```
[ ! -z $2 ] && eval key${ID}_end=$3
```

Would really appreciate any advice / pointers with this.\

Thank you

Comment: If you want to be able to use bash-only syntax (rather than writing for POSIX sh), you should start your script with `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh` -- even if `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, it will disable a number of non-POSIX extensions when invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely going to have to use an intermediary variable:

```
key1_begin=abc
var="key${ID}_begin"
echo "$var=${!var}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that and to Nosid. I now use KEY=key${ID}_begin  and to read echo $KEY =  ${!KEY}   and to write eval ${KEY}=$2.

Comment: @rb20 eval is opening yourself to security holes -- instead of using it, consider the approaches given at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 0):

Just as this (assume bash):

```
#! /bin/sh
ID=2
source mychild.sh
keyid="key${ID}_begin"
echo "key${ID}_begin = ${!keyid}"
```

In short, in bash, you can

```
var=${!i}
```

Or on other shells:

```
var=`eval echo \$$i`
```